# can we view xml in case of web services?

Tags: service

when ever i am consuming a web service xml is received and sent right...is there a way to view this xml...i need to see the exact structure to fine the errors...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It really depends on the library/language/framework you are using. Most of them can dump request/response messages to a log file.

Alternatively you can always use Ethereal/Wireshark to sniff the network and see what is actually going on (assuming your stream is not encrypted)

Answer (score 0):

One "brute force" way would be to use [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) to capture the network traffic, right click one of the packets from the exchange and do "Follow TCP Stream", which will give you8 a nice view of both the sent and recieved XML in one spot.

Comment: i think there has to be a easier way of doing this ...i am creating a java application that consumes a web service..i use the eclipse ide...when i run the application i get a exception ....it would be really helpful to be able to see the xml that the application generates and send in response to which i get a exception..

Comment: what i understand is soap message are sent back and forth right...so is there a way to view these soap messages...?